# How did the Edo Tensei reanimated Second Mizukage summon the Giant Clam?

Tags: naruto

As I understand, summoning requires blood sacrifice, contract and chakra from the jutsu user. Only Nagato (Rinnegan user) is the exception because he uses the Animal Path. He doesn't require hand seals or blood sacrifice.

How did the Edo Tensei reanimated Second Mizukage summon the Giant Clam without blood sacrifice? **I assume Edo Tensei bodies don't have blood.**

[image: The Second Mizukage and his clam]

Comment: Edo tense characters do possess blood. Who said they don't? They won't be destroyed but! When they become like paper or dust when get hit is just a presentation of their in-destruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He probably summoned the clam the normal way with blood. The anime / manga probably just skipped the summoning scene because this isn't a major character and the panels could be better filled with other scenes.

Edo Tensei reanimated characters do in fact have blood. I believe there are a few examples, but the only one that comes to mind at the moment is Itachi's eyes bleeding after using Amaterasu.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform Edo Tensei you need a host. While Kabuto illustrated how Edo Tensei is performed to Tobi, you must have noticed that Kabuto used a host for it.

Once the ET is successful, the body will retain the properties of Edo Tensei jutsu, i.e. the body cannot be destroyed (for instance, if the body is cut or if it was pierced, it would wrap itself with tiny bits of paper, it cannot be felt by the reanimated souls).

But the host (**which is present inside ET's body**) does contain blood. With help of that, any person under the influence of ET can perform Kuchiyose no Jutsu. **Don't forget that Edo Tensei is a Summoning Technique in itself.**

Mizukage is a high level shinobi, so he doesn't need to perform any handseals.

**Ist Reference**
**Click** [here](http://animemagics.wikia.com/wiki/Ninpo_%E2%80%A2_Kuchiyose_%E2%80%A2_Edo_Tensei) **to know more about Edo Tensei**

**IInd Reference**
**Click** [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation) **to know more about Edo Tensei**

Comment: Can you provide proof that says Edo Tensei is part of Kuchiyose no Jutsu? I am pretty sure they are different.

Comment: Sure Please do visit this website :-  http://animemagics.wikia.com/wiki/Ninpo_%E2%80%A2_Kuchiyose_%E2%80%A2_Edo_Tensei

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know the full name was Kuchiyose : Edo Tensei or the fact that kuchiyose just means summoning. I guess my confusion here is that Kuchiyose no jutsu to summon contracted animals requires blood whereas Edo Tensei doesn't.

Comment: @krikara exatly.... :)....even i am making that assumption too.....

Comment: please do vote me up incase if I have answered your question :)